# "hug" vs "embrace" vs "cuddle" (nouns)

Tags: meaning, poetry

According to Cambridge Dictionary these three words are synonyms (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cuddle).

How would you order these three words in terms of which is more loving?

Also which one of these do you think is more literary and less used (up)?

Keep in mind that I am talking about these words as nouns. It is not necessary that whatever applies for the respective verbs ("to hug", "to embrace", "to cuddle") applies also for the nouns.

For example, you can think of these words in the following poetic line (which is addressed to a lover):

"...I wish time would you bring you eventually in my hug/embrace/cuddle...".

Comment: Why are you discarding the verb usage and meanings? If you look in the dictionary the verb sense has priority over the noun, and besides, they are virtually the same. Do you want to know when the noun meaning is different from its verbal expression?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mari-LouA. I am not discarding it but I am simply specifying on what I want to focus. The reason is that not all verbs has the same meaning with their respective nouns. Think about the words "senses" and to "to sense". The former has mainly a physical baggage (e.g. taste is a sense etc) while the latter one has mainly an emotional baggage (e.g. "I sense you" like "I feel you"). Both of the these words have an emotional and a physical baggage respectively but it is not their main one.

Comment: I am not claiming that this necessarily applies for all kind of words but I just noted this since I was not sure about what applies for these three words at my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By sharing contexts in which these words are frequently used, I think I can best illustrate the differences in the words more than the strict dictionary definitions would.

*Verb vs Noun* I think the two usages go hand in hand without an important contrast.  For examples: "The two enjoyed a cuddle" and "The boy cuddled with his stuffed animal" "They shared a warm embrace" vs "They embraced at their re-union",  "He gave him a big hug" and "He hugged him in support after the event" - I cannot think of a noun usage that isn't directly tied to one of the primary verb usages of the words.

*Loving* ? - That word is too vague, however I believe my explanations below illustrate the different sorts of 'love' ... expressed empathy or comfort or closeness as they connect to each word.

*Used up*?  I'm not sure any of the words are overused to the point of "triteness". They certainly have different levels of  "elevation".  If you wanted to break a reader from convention other words might do that better even if these are still excellent at describing certain natures.

### cuddle

Maybe: *a warm, comforting, luxuriating-in-the-contact related wrapping of arms and/or some torso to torso contact* ? One will frequently hear the word 'cuddle' used in conjunction with a 'stuffed animal' in a non-sexual way although one can also cuddle with a lover. Even when lovers cuddle (or "find time for ~a~ cuddle" )  arousal would be more the side-effect than a goal ... however, cuddling with a colleague would suggest some sexuality.  Note:(edit) Cuddle almost always suggests sitting, laying or at least leaning in some shelter (although 'huddle' would be more the non-sexual leaning/bunching together). Also there is a Strong suggestion that you were 'warming' by cuddling; I suppose two people could cuddle, for the intimacy alone, on a hot day yet cuddling while sweating is a bit non-idiomatic. A person can even cuddle up with a book in front of a warm fire.. alone,  but one wouldn't cuddle up with a book on a chaise lounge in the desert sun.  As a noun, it means an intimacy between people from contact, but I would say it brings that "giving warmth to each other" flavor along with it.. both figuratively and literally.

### embrace

One can Embrace a lover (or give them an embrace) but it would also be common for a noble laureate to embrace a former associate when reuniting years later.' One could embrace a new technology, and one could speak of the "embrace" of a new technology as a noun.

Embrace, in my opinion, is the notion of "bringing close" as well as the idea of arms around.  Heavy doses of "engaging" and "encounter proactively" along with the "grasping arms about" which could be more metaphorical with that word.

### hug

*Hug* walks between the *cuddle* and the *embrace*. It includes both the mutual comfort of wrapping arms associated with a cuddle, and the drawing close in the case of an embrace.  In combination, a hug I believe, carries a lot of Communication of Affection and Support from one person to the other. Hugs can show flavors of affection in many situations: A child can give a little hug to their puppy, a lover can hug a lover, a colleague can hug a long lost colleague. But, very very frequently, there is some notion of 'security' of a hug (or a hug of support - letting them feel more secure). One can hug a wall for cover, and even though the noun form would not be used as commonly in that notion.

If I were to drastically oversimplify the overlap between the words,

I might use **"sensory based affection"** for cuddle,  **"security"** for hug, and **"signaled engagement of spirit"** for embrace ... even if any one can also sometimes situation-ally have the others, it is hard for any of those words to ever not have those core meanings while the others might be used without them.

---

Sexuality (as OP requested extra in a comment) -  all the words could be used with or without sexuality involved.

- I do not think I could order the words in terms of sexuality because, it is more the difference in their *nature* of intimacy *than* the *degree* of sexuality.

Cuddle is the most intimate by nature .. however it ~almost~ implies -physical intimacy that is not sex-  "Did you have sex with him? No, we just cuddled on the couch and talked". I wouldn't assume that even meant heavy kissing and groping. While a couple might cuddle before or after sex, that is generally separate from foreplay  ("we were cuddling and one thing led to another and we started .. ) .. and of course a cuddle could be for one's own child as mentioned.

Hug -  I would say that a hug is also almost purposefully divorced in intent from sexuality -  For example if someone objected to unwanted wrapping of arms they would call it a "grab" or a "put his arms around me" because calling it a hug might give the other the benefit of a doubt that they had good intentions (slightly).  One could hug a distraught stranger if the right demeanor were struck and the differences and situation would be unlikely to be construed as sexual (in which case it wouldn't really be a simple hug then).  Hugging a lover is almost a sign of the non-sexual bond of love you share - one of mutual support and aid ... which of course could lead to sexuality as trust is so important and the contact helps get things going yet...

Oddly,  while Embrace is probably the least intimate by default (one could embrace a technology without any hint of human vulnerability),  I would almost suggest that, IF you were writing a sexually charged scene "embrace" would be the most sexual in terms of "heat of passion" - A physical lust is not the only or primary type of sexuality however, if that carnal aspect were what was being emphasized, the care, intimacy and personal love and respect inherent in a cuddle or a hug would distract from "carnality" of the situation. It depends on what one wants to express in a scene or a song etc. .

... as I mentioned in my above section, I believe that "embrace" suggests an active engagement ... and while that does not necessarily suggest any sexuality when it does apply to sexuality it is more of a "all in" thing.

> "The couple cuddled on the beach" – Oh, that's cute and lovely.
>
> "The couple hugged on the beach"  – How nice to find someone you like who likes you back.
>
> "The two ran together and embraced on the sand, silhouetted by the sun setting on the horizon behind them."   - cue that dramatic music in the Hollywood film , cover the children's eyes.

If you are looking for "passion" when you mean sexuality, *embrace* might be better,  if you are looking for a bond of trust in sexuality perhaps *hug*, if you're looking for the private closeness and vulnerability of sexuality perhaps *cuddle*?

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer @Tom22. I will probably tick it as correct but firstly I just want to ask you if you can edit your post to answer also the following relevant question: How would you order these three words in terms of which implies more sexual intimacy?  Notice that I am saying "also" because it is not necessary that this is the primary connotation of this word. Personally, I am inclined to think that "cuddle" is the word for this (even though it has also many non-sexual connotations like cuddling a child etc)

Comment: I tried some additional explanation of the words in connection to sexuality.  It got a bit long though .. hope it helps .. the very last paragraph sums up the different sexual natures of each in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I find the whole post very well-written so I will tick it as correct (unless any super-specialist comes and writes something better). However, let me only note the following. Hence, the debate is really between "embrace" and "cuddle" regarding sexual intimacy. I have the impression that in your own examples you are identifying emotional intensity with sexual intimacy which is not exactly a so accurate premise. To start with, notice that in your "embrace" example the two people who were running to each other may be a parent and her/his child.

Comment: "Embrace" is much more appropriate in this case since it matches to high intensity actions (dramatic tone, running to each other etc). On the other hand, "cuddle" matches to more low intensity actions, for example "let's sit and cuddle"; you are not really doing something so intense when you are cuddling with somebody. However, my impression is that this does not exactly imply that "embrace" is more expressive of sexual intimacy than "cuddle".

Comment: Actually, my impression is that except for some obvious cases (e.g. when you are cuddling a child or a pet etc) "cuddle" is more attached to sexual intimacy than "embrace" which is a "high intensity" word and in this sense it matches to the high intensity of sexual moments but it is not exactly so much about sexual intimacy. In any case, keep in mind that I am a young non-native English speaker so there is high probability that I am wrong but I simply wanted to highlight this distinction between emotional intensity and sexual intimacy regarding these two words.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit  I agree with your comments and felt that I had was very very careful to make those distinctions throughout.  I was very careful not to pass judgement on what is or what is not sexual .   Intimacy is one type of sexuality, and cuddling is intimacy.. so much so that I pointed out that it really can't be used in a neutral non sexual way safely in the workplace.  However, Love is also a part of sexuality and a hug has more love in a willful expression of personal support.  As you read correctly and I agree Embrace  on the whole is action closer to "lust" - a third sexuality.

Comment: @Poete_Maudit   Cuddle and hug are almost insist that there is a gentle and kind interaction ... very appropiate for emotionally connected sex.  However, without even getting violent, if one was describing the passionate sex that near strangers might have with each other... perhaps more akin to two playing tennis together .. an athletic mingling of their bodies ..  'embrace' doesn't carry the 'burden' of intimacy and is more free to be applied to the carnal attention.  You do understand the words correctly.. it is the situation that would lead you to choose the word.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Tom22. Yes I agree to what you said so eventually you may think of my last comments as one more concise formulation of what you already stated at your post. I think that even this gives something interesting...

Answer (score 0):

All three words denote affection; however it would seem only "hug" and "embrace" are truly synonymous from the standpoint of envisioning a group hug/embrace versus a "cuddle". Cuddling traditionally connotes two entities instead of several; although, technically it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

You give someone a `hug` when you meet them.

The mom `embraced` the baby in the cold weather.

New startups `embraced` Linux.

You `cuddle` with your partner or your pet.

These words are closely related, but still with different meanings. `Hug` sounds more like a momentary action to show affection. `Embrace` seems to last longer. `Cuddle` sounds like the whole process that you enjoyed when physically close to someone.

Comment: The question is asking about the noun forms of all these words. Most of your example sentences are using them as verbs.